# In current C++ and Java, double type and float type : if (x == 0.0) is correct?

Tags: java, c++, floating-point, double

In my **old knowledge**: when we want to check whether a double or float is equal 0.0, 
we **should not** write like this:

```
double x = 0.0;
if (x == 0.0) System.out.println("yes");
else System.out.println("no");
```

But several minutes ago, I tried it again, under ***Java(1.7)*** and ***C++(Apple LLVM version 6.0)***, there is no problem to write like that! I have tried both "double" type and "float" type under Java and C++, respectively.

**My question:**

- Did I miss something, or we really can check the double or float like
  that under current Java and C++.
- If we can, whether we can do it under early version of Java and C++?

---

**Conclusion(based on all helps):**
We **should not** use "float == float or double == double" to check whether two floats or two doubles are equal(*if we want to get the right answer*), the **reasons** are in all answers and comments **below**.

---

**Edition(First time):**
**Thank you so much for all help!**
But one minute ago, I just try these under Java(1.7), all show "***yes***", 
it seems we **really can do it** under current Java!

```
float x = 0.0f;
if (x == 0) System.out.println("yes");
else System.out.println("no");

float y = 100.0f - 50.0f*2.0f + 45.0f*3 - 135.0f;
if (y == 0.0f) System.out.println("yes");
else System.out.println("no");

if (100.0f - 50.0f*2.0f + 45.0f*3 - 135.0f == 0.0f) System.out.println("yes");
else System.out.println("no");
```

---

**Edition(Second Time):**
But I have tried this, Java also shows "***yes***", (under Java(1.7)).
I try to ***eliminate compiler's "pre-compute"***, and split the computation into several steps.

```
float a = 100.0f;
float b = 50.0f;
float c = 2.0f;
float bc = b * c;
System.out.println("b*c = " + bc);

float d = 45.0f;
float e = 3.0f;
float de = d * e;
System.out.println("d*e = " + de);

float f = 135.0f;

float g = a - bc + de - f;
float h = 0.0f;
if (g == h) System.out.println("yes");
else System.out.println("no");
```

---

**Edition(Third Time):**

Thank you for @DiegoBasch's **counterexample** (for float == float):
This time Java(1.7) shows "***no***".

```
float m = 0.37f - 0.36f;
float n = 0.01f;
if (m - n == 0.0f) System.out.println("yes");
else System.out.println("no");
```

Comment: `x` is exactly `0`, so it is OK. The problem is when `x` is the result of a sequence of operations that mathematically would yield `0`, but do not result in `0.0` for numerical reasons.

Comment: To elaborate on what @juanchopanza said, in your case that will evaluate to true, but you cannot guarantee that `100.0 - 50.0 * 2.0 == 0.0` even though mathematically it should.

Comment: Floating points are often described as "approximate" values, which is misleading. A floating point number has an exact value, it's just that this value may not be exactly what you expect due to limited precision. As such, if you're comparing it to an expected value, you should ask not "are they exactly the same" but rather "are they close enough." `0.0` is no different than `1.3` or `3.14159` in that sense.

Comment: @Cyber Actually, you can guarantee that your expression will be equal, because the numbers involved can be represented exactly.  Some numbers can; `1.3` and `3.14159` cannot.  To get a good understanding of how floats are represented, see my [How Does Floating-Point Work](http://www.adambeneschan.com/How-Does-Floating-Point-Work) site; try typing in `100.0`, `1.3`, `3.14159`, etc., and see how those numbers are represented as `float` or `double`.

Comment: Hi thank you for all helps, but it seems that we really can do it under Java(1.7), see my edition.

Comment: I would keep to the advice of the experts and standard documents instead of relying on 3 randomly chosen calculations... See e.g. effective Java and the Java language specifications.

Comment: Here `if ((0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3) == 0)`. The compiler even knows that anything that follows is dead code.

Comment: @Zhaonan regarding your edit: no, you can't do it. Reasons your example is working _could_ be that your numbers can be represented exactly or that your hard coded term can be resolved at compile time.

Comment: @Zhaonan This has nothing to do with Java 7.  It is because the numbers you're using, and the intermediate results, can be represented exactly in the machine.  Values which are integers are OK up to 16777215 for a `float` (9007199254740992 for a `double`).  No rounding is involved.  For larger integers, or non-integers, you still can't necessarily use `==` accurately.

Comment: @fxfour That would be "grand", if pre-calculation by the compiler would change the result.

Comment: @owlstead so I guess it isn't the case, thanks for your clarification.

Comment: @owlstead Interestingly (or not, if you don't care), in Ada the pre-calculation *would* change the result.  The rules of that language are that any computation involving constant values (known at compile time) must be done exactly; they aren't converted to 32- or 64-bit floats until all the constant calculations are done.  Basically, Ada compilers have to have the equivalent of `BigDecimal` in them.  That's the only language I know of with that kind of rule.

Comment: Hi all, I try to eliminate the compiler's "pre-compute", and split the computation into several steps, but Java also shows "yes", see the "Edition(second time)".

Comment: Without the context, it's impossible to tell whether your usage of == will be valid or not. If using == were ALLWAYS invalid, then all languages would just remove the == operator for floating points. The rule should be: use float equality only if you are sure of what you are doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is legal.  The problem is that when you're doing calculations involving floating-point numbers, there will be rounding errors, and therefore in many cases checking for exactly 0 (or checking two numbers for equality) will not work.

This code is fine in any language since you haven't done anything that would cause rounding:

```
double x = 0.0;
if (x == 0.0) System.out.println("yes");
else System.out.println("no");
```

This code may not be fine, though:

```
double a1 = ...something...;
double a2 = ...something...;
double a3 = a1 / a2;
double a4 = a3 * a2;
double a5 = a4 - a1;
if (a5 == 0.0) ...
```

Even though mathematically `a5` should be 0, in practice the `==` operation may return `false` because of rounding.

This requires an understanding of how floating-point is handled in a computer; it has nothing to do with any language or version of a language.  One reference is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: [This site](http://floating-point-gui.de/) is often cited as "Goldberg's paper in digestible form."

Comment: Hi @ajb, thank you so much for your help, but I just have tried it with some computation under Java(1.7) it works.....see my edition, it seems we really can do it under Java now.

Comment: @Zhaonan see my comment in response to your edit.  `==` will work with _some_ numbers, and that has always been the case.  It will not work in all cases.  It has nothing to do with the Java version.

Comment: @Hi ajb, thank you so much, I think Diego Basch found a counterexample, you are right, it will not work in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

To complement ajb's answer, here's an example of numerical error. You don't need many calculations for it to happen.

```
    double a = 0.37 - 0.36; // 0.010000000000000009
    double b = 0.01;
    System.out.println (a - b == 0.0); // false
```

Comment: Hi @Diego Basch, thank you so much for your counterexample, now I believe the "float == float" will not work under all cases.